# Getting response via ajax when calling a python script that contains a loop

Tags: python, ajax, sockets, loops

I'm using AJAX Post to call a python script that contains a server socket that continuously listen for new incoming data in a **while True** loop. Because of the loop, the script is never finished, therefore I can't access the data using the *success*, nor the *done* cases from AJAX. I would like to use the data received via socket to update elements in my HTML page.

AJAX Code:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "../../cgi-bin/python-script",
       data: {iframe: id_iframe}, 
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
             alert(response);
       },
       error: function(){
             console.log("Error creating socket.");
       }
}).done(function(data){
       console.log(data);
       alert(data);
});
```

Python Code:

```
while True:
        connection, address = serversocket.accept()
        buf = connection.recv(PATH_MAX) 

        data = pickle.loads(buf)

        if data:
            print("\nData received: " + data[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use celery to run your code async and your main thread won't be blocked.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? I have no clue how to work with celery. 
From what I quickly read at http://www.celeryproject.org/, it seems to be what I need.

Comment: Follow by [tutorial] (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) There several main points: you should have broker for example redis or rabbitmq, you should run celery worker like `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info` and you should have task with your loop. After a somebody sends request you should call this task with `apply_async`.